# focus not going to listitems in browse mode nvda

Tags: accessibility, jaws-screen-reader, nvda

similar thing happening here with this code. Browse mode focus not going to list items.

```
 {<ul style="
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    "><li class="attachmentsContainerStyle-319" style="
        text-align: unset;
    " role="listitem" aria-setsize="2" aria-posinset="1">Screenshot 2023-01-09 at 4.34.36 PM_2023-01-12T17:10:00.6072590Z.png</li><li class="attachmentsContainerStyle-319" role="listitem" aria-setsize="2" aria-posinset="2"><p class="attachmentStyle-320"><i data-icon-name="TextDocument" aria-hidden="true" class="attachmentIconStyle-365"></i> Screenshot 2023-01-09 at 4.34.36 PM_2023-01-12T17:10:47.4149896Z.png</p><div><button type="button" class="ms-Link jaIaction-366" aria-disabled="false"><i data-icon-name="Download" aria-hidden="true" class="jaIactioIcon-367"></i>Download</button><button type="button" class="ms-Link jaIaction2-368" aria-disabled="false"><i data-icon-name="Delete" aria-hidden="true" class="jaIactioIcon-367"></i>Delete</button></div></li></ul>}
```

I want the screenreader to read list item 1 of 2 but the focus directly going to the document name in the list item that is in <p> container.

Comment: Could you please render your HTML more readable and ideally make it an interactive code snippet, so that people can easily reproduce the issue? The HTML is invalid, there is a closed </div> after the </p>. That might have to do with the issue? It‘s also quite verbose and unnecessarily adding aria attributes that are already implicit like `<li role="listitem">`.

Comment: Another question is what you mean by _focus_. Only interactive elements should be/are focusable. That would be the first button, which is inside the second list item, so it’s correct that it’s focussed first on tab. If you would like to read the list with a screen reader, you should use the arrow keys to read, not tab. Did you actually test with Talkback, or why did you add `android-a11y`?

Answer (score 0):

Your original question is about NVDA and browse mode but you tagged the question with `android-a11y`. I'm going to ignore android for now.

With NVDA in browse mode, did you try navigating to your list using the <kbd>L</kbd> key or to each list item using the <kbd>i</kbd> key?

If your main concern is hearing "X of Y" as you navigate each list item, that's totally up to the screen reader itself in addition to **user** settings. A user can change their verbosity settings and totally turn off the announcement for a list start/end as well as the position within the list, so there's no way you can force that announcement other than having literal "X of Y" text in your code (visibly hidden) for the screen reader to announce.

I noticed you had `aria-postinset` and `aria-setsize` in your sample code.  I'm assuming you were trying to force the "X of Y" announcement.  Those attributes are not needed when you're using semantic `<ul>` or `<ol>` elements and, as you probably noticed with your testing, does not force the "X of Y" announcement.  That again is up to the screen reader software and the user settings.

Same with `role="listitem"` - it's not needed in your example.