# Grouping buttons - ARIA

Tags: javascript, html, wai-aria

I have a group of 2~3 buttons inside one flex, is there a way to announce to the user that the buttons are grouped and specify which button is focused?

Example: I have 3 buttons - "Cancel" - "Modify" - "Confirm". I want it to be announced as "Cancel button 1 of 3", not necessary on this order.
PS: Avoid changing the buttons aria-label and role.

```
<div id="flxButtons">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <input id="btnCancel" type="button" role="button" value="CANCEL">
  </div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <input id="btnModify" type="button" role="button" value="MODIFY">
  </div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <input id="btnNext" type="button" role="button" value="NEXT">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One might be tempted to use [`aria-setsize`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-setsize) and [`aria-posinset`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-posinset) on the buttons but those attributes are only valid on listitems and treeitems, so you **can't** do this:

```
<input id="btnCancel" type="button" role="button" value="CANCEL" aria-posinset="1" aria-setsize="3">
```

However, you could add list semantics to the `<div>` around each button (or use a real `<ul>`), but that doesn't guarantee you'll hear "X of Y" on each button because that's up to the screen reader and user settings. See [focus not going to listitems in browse mode nvda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75100483/focus-not-going-to-listitems-in-browse-mode-nvda/75113919#75113919) for details.

```
<div id="flxButtons" role="list" aria-label="my group of buttons">
  <div id="wrapper" role="listitem">
    <input id="btnCancel" type="button" role="button" value="CANCEL">
  </div>
  <div id="wrapper" role="listitem">
    <input id="btnModify" type="button" role="button" value="MODIFY">
  </div>
  <div id="wrapper" role="listitem">
    <input id="btnNext" type="button" role="button" value="NEXT">
  </div>
</div>
```

As far as the grouping itself, in the example above, specifying `role="list"` on the outer container will give you a grouping.  If you don't want to use lists, you can use `role="region"` **and** specify an `aria-label`.

```
<div id="flxButtons" role="region" aria-label="my group of buttons">
```

If you always want to force "X of Y" to be announced, regardless of the users screen reader settings, you'd have to literally add that text. You could either make that text part of the button label (but not visible) or you could associate the text with the button's descrption. The latter might be slightly better since you didn't want to change the button's label.  However, it's a little messy to do so with the current ARIA spec because you only have [`aria-describedby`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-describedby), which requires the ID of the element that has the description, so you have to create a new DOM element that has the description.

In ARIA 1.3, there will be an [`aria-description`](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#aria-description) which takes a literal string so it'll be easier when that spec is approved.

So in the current ARIA spec, using `aria-describedby`, you could have something like this:

```
<div style="display:none">
  <div id="desc1">1 of 3</div>
  <div id="desc2">2 of 3</div>
  <div id="desc3">3 of 3</div>
</div>

<div id="flxButtons" role="region" aria-label="my group of buttons">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <input id="btnCancel" type="button" role="button" value="CANCEL" aria-describedby="desc1">
  </div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <input id="btnModify" type="button" role="button" value="MODIFY" aria-describedby="desc2">
  </div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <input id="btnNext" type="button" role="button" value="NEXT" aria-describedby="desc3">
  </div>
</div>
```